# What is the best way for email validation using patterns in Angular2?

Tags: html, validation, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular2-template

I am working with the form validation in which the form contains a email field and is of type text (i.e) input[type='text']. I used pattern for validating email this means a custom validation using RegExp.

Now my problem is I can validate whether the field is empty or not. But, when coming to patterns validation I cant get the results as expected.

So All I need is a way to validate the patterns using Angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using reactive forms in Angular2 (I think it came in version 4.2.5) You can set the validators the form control will use and it has email validation built in.

Please see angular documentation for more information.

https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators

EDIT:

Here is an example Plunker with it working.

[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Axj9wULcSYLa1nvKFyq?p=preview)

Below is a copy of the code

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="userform">
          <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" formControlName="userEmail" />
                  <p *ngIf="userform.get('userEmail').hasError('email') && !userform.controls['userEmail'].valid && userform.get('userEmail').touched">Email is invalid.</p>
          </div>
        </form>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
    userform: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

    buildForm() {
        this.userform = this._fb.group({
            userEmail: [null, Validators.email]
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.buildForm();
    }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: can you give some examples on this

Comment: @Ram added an example for you

Comment: Thanks for the example

Answer (score 0):

You can now simply use `email` as attribute (directive in angular4) now in angular to validate email validation like this

```
<input type="email" name="email" ngModel email>
```

For more information you can refer here

- https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator